# What is the idiomatic way to write prepend for a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I've started writing a linked-list implementation in C:

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    node *next;
    int value;
};
```

I can easily write the function append which attaches a new node to the end of the list:

```
void append(node *head, int value) {
    if (! head->next) {
        head->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->next->value = value;
        return;
    }

    append(head->next, value);
}
```

If I were writing prepend using a functional language like Scheme, the obvious thing to do would be to simply return a new node with "next" pointing to the previous head:

```
(define (prepend head value)
        (cons value head))
```

and I can write this easily in C:

```
node *prepend(node *old_head, int value) {
    node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->value = value;
    head->next = old_head;

    return head;
}
```

but now my `append` function doesn't return anything and just mutates the list, while my `prepend` function *does* return something and doesn't mutate the original list. This is a side effect of how linked lists are implemented, but it feels wrong.

One solution might be to rewrite `prepend` to add a new node, but use the previous head for the new value and the new node for the old head's value...

```
void prepend(node *head, int value) {
    node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    memcpy(new, head, sizeof(node));

    head->next = new;
    head->value = value;
}
```

but something about this also feels wrong.

Another solution might be to represent a list not as the head node, but as a different struct which points to the head node:

```
typedef struct list list;
struct list {
    node *head;
};
```

Now my `prepend` function can just change where `list->head` points, and it doesn't have to return anything. This feels the cleanest, but it introduces additional baggage; now I have to use a helper function for append and many other functions (or implement them differently).

What's the idiomatic way to implement this function in C?

---

Note: I'm new to C and would appreciate any comments regarding my code style or correctness, even if unrelated to the question.

Comment: How do you append to an empty list? Think about this and it will clarify your question about prepending.

Comment: `append` needs `head->next->next = NULL;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: to clarify, you're saying that when I create a new node via malloc I need to set the `next` pointer to NULL explicitly? So the way I've written it now is illegal and/or undefined behavior?

Comment: yes, there is no assurance that  `if (! head-> next)` to function properly. malloc does not initialize the area secured.

Comment: Minor: although this is C and OK, avoiding C++ keywords like `new` as variable names has advantages including the format engine SO uses.  `new` is colored as if it were a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "right" answer in my opinion, but I like the `struct list` approach.  You can even make it opaque to the end user.  Then you could change the underlying implementation to be a doubly linked list or backed by array, and the user wouldn't have to change any code to take advantage of it.